# laravel how to link external javascript files

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, controller, view

i have my js assets in this folder:

---public
   ---js

here is my html file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>  
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> My Ebay Script</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/js/callrequest.js" />   
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My website</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

yet it does not load the javascript file...why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes relative paths so every time domain name is going to change it is good practice to use Laravel`s HTML class or asset() to load css and javascript file it directly points to public directory so no need to write public.

**With Blade syntax**
In Laravel 4 you can use the HTML class, it's default included in the Laravel Framework package:

```
Javascript:

{{ HTML::script('js/callrequest.js') }}

Stylesheet:

{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

**Without blade you can make link to assets**

using asset()

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo asset('js/callrequest.js')?>" />
```

refer this urls helper function of laravel for more detail
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/helpers#urls

Comment: in view its a blade syntax , are you using blade ?

Comment: no just html...so w/o using blade what is correct path for regular script tag

Comment: ok lets say i put my javascript file in public/js, now how do i write the script tag

Comment: you have created files in view folder with php extension is that right ?

Comment: please check edited answer, it that working for you ?

Comment: yes thats perfect.  I don't like blade and will never use it, so thanks.

Comment: glade that my answer helps you, its developer`s choice to use blade or not :D

Answer (score 0):

You can do that, by this way.. I made a folder called 'assets' in public folder then I just use asset() function and called my CSS and JS file.

BTW: This is for Laravel-5

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.css')}}>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}"><script src="{{asset('assets/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')}}"></script>
<script src="{{asset('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}></script>`